# Is there safe_cast in the standard c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

It looks like there is a safe_cast in the visual c++, which looks similar to dynamic_cast.

I am wondering if safe_cast is in the standard c++?

Comment: what would your safe_cast do that dynamic_cast doesn't?

Comment: safe_cast throws on invalid cast, just like casting in Java. dynamic_cast returns NULL pointer non fail

Comment: `&dynamic_cast<Foo&>(*p)`

Comment: @Bartek ... and `dynamic_cast` requires the RTTI so you probably need to deal with some compiler flag to be sure to get the right behaviour and it cost you something at runtime, simply because it happens at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

safe_cast is used in C++/CLI. There is no such standard construction in C++.

Answer (score 3):

safe_cast is not standard c++ type casting.
Only 4 casting operators available

```
1.dynamic_cast <new_type> (expression)
2.reinterpret_cast <new_type> (expression)
3.static_cast <new_type> (expression)
4.const_cast <new_type> (expression)
```

Comment: in C++11 there are `std::move` and `std::forward` too, and they are both casting that will happen at compile-time.

Comment: @user But they aren't operators built into the language, just functions.

Comment: @AlanStokes the standard library is "standard" for a reason ... you can consider any part of the standard library as part of the C++ standard simply because there is 1 ISO document to rule them all.

Comment: @user The library/language distinction is still useful (and I think freestanding mode still exists, which complicates things). All I was saying is while `std::move` is jolly useful, and obviously implemented by a cast, it isn't technically a cast operator.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a "safe" cast myself, and found what I was looking for in  boost::polymorphic_cast. It throws an exception when the cast is invalid or when trying to cast from nullptr. If the type is not polymorphic (i.e. no virtual members), it gives compile time error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\polymorphic_cast.hpp>

class Base{
    public: virtual ~Base() = default;
};

class D1 : public Base{
    public: virtual ~D1() = default;
};

class D2 : public Base{
    public: virtual ~D2() = default;
};


int main(void)
{
    D1 d1;
    Base* b = &d1;
    Base* b2 = nullptr;

    std::cout << "\n---Testing valid cast---\n";
    std::cout << "cast from base to d1: " << boost::polymorphic_cast<D1*>(b) << "\n";

    try {
        std::cout << "\n---Testing invalid cast---\n";
        std::cout << "base to d2: " << boost::polymorphic_cast<D2*>(b) << "\n";
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "cast from based to d2 failed\n";
    }

    try {
        std::cout << "\n---Testing nullptr cast---\n";
        std::cout << "null to d1: " << boost::polymorphic_cast<D1*>(b2) << "\n";
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cout << "cast from null to d1 failed\n";
    }
}
```

gives output:

```
---Testing valid cast---
cast from base to d1: 00AFFBD4

---Testing invalid cast---
cast from based to d2 failed

---Testing nullptr cast---
cast from null to d1 failed
```

Comment: In other words, `&std::dynamic_cast<D1&>(*b)`? (though you'd have to do the NULL case yourself ofc). This isn't really `safe_cast`, it's just the throwing version of `dynamic_cast` plus a null check.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as far as I am aware, this is exactly what a safe_cast is, something that throws an exception if the the cast is invalid(instead of giving you undefined behavior), so that you can catch it and recover. It is a well defined behavior so I would call it "safe". Saves you from having to write the if/else that you need with dynamic_cast. That's also what C++/CLI's safe_cast does (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/safe-cast-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2017) which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: I suspect the main difference with `safe_cast` is that it works on C++/CLI types ;) So not really a factor in C++. Anyway I guess my point is that Boost is overkill for this; the stdlib already (pretty much) has something that does what you need, though wrapping it to check NULL could be useful and gets you what you describe

Comment: Fair enough, if I was not using boost already, I wouldn't use it just for this :) If you use boost, it probably makes sense to use it instead of making your own version.

Comment: Could be, though a simple `dynamic_cast` will still be clearer to your readers.